# Layout XML attribute names

Tags: xml, androidplot

Having originally used the 0.6.0 dynamic example as the basis for viewing sampled data, I have recently tried updating this to 1.4.2 and as part of that have stumbled over the correct way to be setting values in the layout file as the refactoring of the AndroidPlot code base between these releases has changed them.

Is there a definitive list of what is available on the XYPlot or better still a grid with a column for the attributes name is different releases?
(I've read on another answer that extracting get/set names from the sources is one approach)

Here is what I had:

```
        androidPlot.borderPaint.color="#E0E0E0"
        androidplot.renderMode="use_background_thread"
        androidPlot.title="History"
        androidPlot.domainLabel="Domain"
        androidPlot.rangeLabel="Range"
        androidPlot.titleWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
        androidPlot.titleWidget.labelPaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.domainLabelWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_label_font_size"
        androidPlot.domainLabelWidget.labelPaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.rangeLabelWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_label_font_size"
        androidPlot.rangeLabelWidget.labelPaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.backgroundPaint.color="#E0E0E0"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.gridBackgroundPaint.color="#E0E0E0"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.domainGridLinePaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.domainOriginLinePaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeGridLinePaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeOriginLinePaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.marginTop="20dp"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.marginLeft="15dp"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.marginBottom="25dp"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.marginRight="10dp"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_tick_label_font_size"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeLabelPaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeOriginLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_tick_label_font_size"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeOriginLabelPaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.domainLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_tick_label_font_size"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.domainLabelPaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.domainOriginLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_tick_label_font_size"
        androidPlot.graphWidget.domainOriginLabelPaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.legendWidget.textPaint.textSize="@dimen/legend_text_font_size"
        androidPlot.legendWidget.textPaint.color="#000000"
        androidPlot.legendWidget.iconSizeMetrics.heightMetric.value="15dp"
        androidPlot.legendWidget.iconSizeMetrics.widthMetric.value="15dp"
        androidPlot.legendWidget.heightMetric.value="25dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the definitive list is the code, a la `attrs.xml`.  A more user-friendly list of attrs along with usage notes etc in markdown format is being worked on though and will be available in an upcoming release of Androidplot.

[Here's a link](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/attrs.md) to the current state of that markdown version in a dev branch.  Unfortunately there is no documentation outside release notes about name changes.

Comment: I see some changes on github today and am slowly getting through this. Would it be possible to expand the inflateParams "Error inflating XML: Setter requires param of unsupported type: " message to provide the name of the paramater?

Comment: hmm...that should [already be happening](https://github.com/FrostDigital/AndroidPlot-Core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/androidplot/util/Configurator.java#L245).  you should only be getting that exception when setting an xml param using Configurator (the old way).

Comment: oops linked to the wrong repo.  code is basically the same but this is the [right link](https://github.com/halfhp/fig/blob/master/figlib/src/main/java/com/halfhp/fig/Fig.java#L222).

Comment: Yes, I had located the error text in inflateParams.
Within the design view,  it reports a TextLabelWidget class is the unsupported type but I'm not able to tell which part of the xml this refers to?
By 'old way/Configurator' - does that refer to the ability for the control to provide its properties in the design view and so changes reflected in the xml?. (I'm not as familiar with the java concepts here as usual work within Visual Studio or on embedded solutions)

Comment: `Configurator` was a pre-aar hack to allow configuring Plot etc. via xml back when it wasn't possible to use styleable attrs in libs due to limitations of jar packaging.  It used reflection to map xml attrs prefixed with `androidPlot` to setters/getters.  In your case, the goal would be to replace Configurator formatted attrs like `androidPlot.title="History"` with first class styleable attrs like `ap:title="history"`. (the former attrs are the ones causing the exception, likely due to refactored / removed getter/setter names in newer versions of androidplot)

Comment: Thank you Nick, I understand now. I can simply supply my own style in my projects style.xml using those in the core project as guide.

Comment: Almost done, just one problem on the four line labels, e.g.:
Error:(406, 51) Color types not allowed (at 'lineLabelTextColorBottom' with value '#000000'). [Fixed] - changed to use "@color/line_labels" instead having defined that as #000000